# Странное окончание причастия в предложении

Tags: согласование, причастия

> Она представила результаты мониторинга влияния санкционных ограничений на бизнес, показавш**ий**, что более 60% предпринимателей в той или иной степени были затронуты санкциями.

Смущает окончание в слове «показавший»...
Мониторинга, показавш**его**? Или что здесь «показало»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в [этой статье](https://vesti-k.ru/news/2022/04/14/60-krymskih-predprinimatelej-zatronuli-sankcii/) имеется такое предложение:
*Обсудили результаты **мониторинга** влияния санкционных ограничений на бизнес, **показавшего**, что более 60% крымских предпринимателей в той или иной степени были затронуты санкциями.*
(Мониторинга — какого? — показавшего; другими словами: мониторинга, который показал, что...)

Смысл, думаю, такой: проводился мониторинг влияния; один из результатов — 60% предпринимателей затронуты санкциями; имеются и другие результаты.
*Показавший* — неверно (бизнес ничего не показывал), просто определяемое слово далеко.

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы, здесь должно быть согласование по "мониторингу". Иначе выходит, что не мониторинг показал, а бизнес показал.

Answer (score 2):

А мне кажется, результаты показали. Тогда *показавшие.*